# PHP recaptcha not working

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have set up the google reCaptcha PHP plugin on this site:

http://benliger.webatu.com/

You can see it displays fine under Contact, however after adding in the necessary PHP into my form_process file the form still submits regardless of whether or not the reCaptcha is filled out. Here is my PHP code that sits in the form_process file:

```
 <?php

    //Check if POST data is set, and not empty, else it will do this every single time, submitted or not

    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $privatekey = "6Le2a_oSAAAAAJ81_yQvCelFMIHiUcG_k6u0S1fd";
      $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

      if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
             "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
      } else {



    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {

        $mail_to = 'benliger@hotmail.com'; // specify your email here

        // Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables
        $name = $_POST['sender_name'];
        $mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];
        $phone = $_POST['sender_phone'];
        $message = $_POST['sender_message'];

        // Construct email subject
        $subject = 'enquiry ' . $name;

        // Construct email body
        $body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;

        // Construct email headers
        $headers = 'From: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

        $mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

        if ($mail_sent == true){ 
            //Echo the message now, because it will be catched in your jQuery listerener (see code below)
            echo 'Thanks for getting in touch!';




         } else { 
            //Echo the message now, because it will be catched in your jQuery listerener (see code below)
            echo 'Message not sent :( Please, get in contact with me directly: benliger@hotmail.com';
        }
        //This exit; is important, else the alert box will be full of the further html code
        exit;

    }
    }
    ?>
```

And my HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST"> 

 <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "6Le2a_oSAAAAAEHu4u35QWlLzxzCYB1JnhFoI0u5"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
```

.... and the rest of my form here

Might be worth noting my send button looks like so:

```
<input class="sendbutton" type="submit" name="send_message" value="Send">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
    //Prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();

var form = $(this);
    //Create an array of input values
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    //Do the ajax request
    $.post('form_process.php',data,function(responseMessage){
resetForm(form); 
        //Alert your message
$( ".mycontactform" ).html('<p>Thanks for getting in touchaaa!</p>');

        //alert(responseMessage);
     });

 });
```

Comment: Are you using the right key when generating? I can't find the problem either.

Comment: Try changing require_once to require.

Comment: You’re checking the CAPTCHA for validity before you even check whether the request was actually made via POST … that makes little sense.

Comment: Could you print_r the output of $resp?

Comment: I tried that Imran and no luck, as you can tell im pretty new to PHP so not entirely sure if the logic is correct, just tried to best follow instructions from googles documentation. @CBroe could you please elaborate on how it should look?

Comment: @Wouter0100 where in the form should i place print_r($resp);

Comment: @BenLiger do you generate the private and public key from google by specifying your domain name ?

Comment: yes that right @ImranTufail

Comment: @BenLiger put the entire php code block above in a `if(!empty($_POST))` its how i use it without issue

Comment: @BenLiger place the print_r($resp);die(); before if (!$resp->is_valid) statement and it will help you. As mentioned by wouter.

Comment: @Parody i tried adding if(!empty($_POST)) at the top of the code but no luck. Not sure if this is exactly what you mean. Imran i placed print_r($resp);die(); before if (!$resp->is_valid)  as per your suggestion too but again no luck.

Comment: it will not resolve problem but it will tell you what the problem is.WE need that output.show that output here so we suggest you solution.

Comment: @ImranTufail the code has been added to the site. Let me know if you can see what you need to now

Comment: I don't think so the code is present on the site.let me explain print_r($resp) will print every thing $resp containing and die() will break the execution of code.but there is nothing on the page and moreover isset($_POST) is not working i think you are routing to wrong page  not the above you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Error is in your jquery code .whatever the response is you are replacing it with
 `<p>Thanks for getting in touchaaa!</p>`

use `alert(responseMessage)` to see the response

so replace `$( ".mycontactform" ).html('<p>Thanks for getting in touchaaa!</p>');`

with  `alert(responseMessage)`

Comment: Solved it! My only question now is could I have it so that when the form is submitted WITH Captcha filled out properly it will echo the message to the html like i had before rather than through the alert javascript box?

Comment: $( ".mycontactform" ).html(responseMessage);

Comment: one last question, dont suppose theres a way to make the reponse message from the failed form come up in alert(responseMessage) and the successfull one to post in html like your suggestion is there?

Comment: make the response array on server and return as json by function json _dump(array) and in jquery function check for corresponding element